# How to place an image into stage as background?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

Is there a way to place an image as a background of a Stage instead of adding it first to an ImageView?

```
        ImageView splash = new ImageView(getClass().getResource("/splash.png").toExternalForm());
        VBox splashLayout = new VBox();
        splashLayout.getChildren().addAll(splash, progressText, loadProgress);
        Scene splashScene = new Scene(splashLayout);
        initStage.setScene(splashScene);
```

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to use CSS with your JavaFx,

here is a code for CSS

```
.root{
    -fx-background-image: url("your_image.jpg");
}
```

and add this css file to your scenes by,

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("myCss.css").toExternalForm());
```